# Liquibase changelog not executed on Micronaut app startup

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, liquibase, micronaut

I have a Java app created using Micronaut and Gradle. I'm trying to create the database tables and insert initial data using Liquibase in a MySQL database running on a docker volume. I want to run the Liquibase changelog on app startup so that all data is added when the application starts.

I followed [this](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-liquibase-gradle-java.html) guide and I've created the Docker volume and changelog files, however the database queries are not being executed during app start up.

This is what I see on Docker desktop app after running `docker-compose up`.

[image: Containers-docker]

[image: Images-docker]

[image: Volumes-docker]

I do not see any errors when I run `./gradlew build` and `./gradlew/run`. However, I can see that the database on docker container is empty when using `docker exec -it mysql-image mysql -uroot -p`.

[image: db-query]

**The Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mysql
LABEL author=me
ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=my_db
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpw
EXPOSE 3306
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  mysql-image:
    build:
      context: ./src/main/resources/db
    container_name: mysql-image
    volumes:
    - mysql-image:/my_db
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE:my_db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:rootpw

volumes:
  mysql-image:
```

**application.yml snippet:**

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-image:3306
    dialect: MYSQL
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    schema-generate: NONE

liquibase:
  enabled: true
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true
      change-log: 'classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml'

endpoints:
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
```

**build.gradle snippet:**

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.5.0"
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.liquibase:micronaut-liquibase")
}
```

**liquibase-changelog.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databaseChangeLog>
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <includeAll path="/scripts/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**sql script file:**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db;
USE my_db;

CREATE TABLE table_a (
    id int(10) not null primary key,
    col_1 varchar(20) not null,
    col_2 varchar(45)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b (
    id int(10) not null primary key,
    col_a varchar(45) not null,
    col_b varchar(45) 
);
```

I'm assuming some configuration in the above files are incorrect or missing and it's causing Liquibase not to run. I'm rather new to Liquibase and Docker and hope you could guide me to run the Liquibase code during app startup.

Comment: 1) your Dockerfile and build phase for mysql are totally useless at this point: you are already passing the environment variables and the exposed port through your `docker-compose.yml` file. 2) your mounted volume is totally useless as is since it is not mounted on the default mysql data path (/var/lib/mysql). You actually end up with your volume which stays empty and an anonymous internal volume mounted on the data path. 3) You are not giving any evidence in your question that the database is empty. How did you check that point ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added above the output from ```docker exec -it mysql-image mysql -uroot -p``` which is how I checked if the db has any tables created.

Comment: Do you have any custom BeanCreatedEventListeners that directly or indirectly inject a datasource?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this, https://www.liquibase.com/blog/plain-sql

> The first line must always be the comment `--liquibase formatted sq`l. This allows typical SQL tools like Oracle sqldeveloper to treat those lines as comments, but gives Liquibase a clue that this file is special. The second line starting with `--changset` is required for each changeset. As with changesets in other formats, each changeset must have an author, a unique identifier, and should be an “atomic unit of change”.